# magento create frontend url like modulename/postidenntity

Tags: php, magento

In magento we creating one module look like blog .

we need to open single record by http://{yourstore}/myextension/{any identity} .

is that possible to create url using Samdoit_Myextension_Controller_Router .
in config file .

```
<default>
    <web>
        <routers>
            <Myextension_myrouter>
                <area>frontend</area>
                <class>Samdoit_Myextension_Controller_Router</class>
            </Myextension_myrouter>
        </routers>
    </web>
</default>
```

is that correct way of creating url

Answer (score 0):

Following is configuration syntax to create front end url

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <router_id>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Samdoit_Myextension</module>
                <frontName>myrouter</frontName>
            </args>
        </router_id>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

To access your blog content, use url like `http://[host]/myrouter/controller/action/param/value`

Comment: I think you IndexController and IndexAction. make action function like public function testAction(), and try like index/test. Accordingly add more actions as you like

Comment: I wont to create more action using code . I need to create url dynamic .like that myextension/test , myextension/test2 , myextension/test3 .... the test,test2.... they are we give the identity for record .

Comment: The structure of Magento URL is like http://[host]/myrouter/controller/action/param/value. So you can any dynamic value in the place of param and value